# Deprecation Notice & ERROR: Dependency installation failed

Tags: laravel, heroku

I am getting this error when am push my project to heroku. What is wrong?

```
Deprecation Notice: Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\n ./app/Http/Controllers/Administrator/Auth/LoginController.php doesding standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phau/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201
remote:        Deprecation Notice: Class App\Models\Vendor located i not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anr:///tmp/build_fd6c0433/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autolo
remote:        Deprecation Notice: Class App\Models\Rider located inot comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anym///tmp/build_fd6c0433/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload
remote:        > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoload
remote:        > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
remote:        
remote:        In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
remote:
remote:          Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvid
remote:
remote:
remote:        Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling eturned with error code 1
remote:  !     WARNING: There was a class not found error in your co
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. 
remote:  !     may be the download or installation of packages, or a
remote:  !     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 
remote:  !     in your 'composer.json'.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts 
remote:  !     timeouts when making external connections, or memory 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Check the above error output closely to determine the
remote:  !     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functi
remote:  !     properly, and that all local changes are committed co
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, ref
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
remote:  !
remote:  !     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during 
remote:  !     check the details above, as they may be related to th
remote:  !     - Your 'composer.lock' is out of date!
remote:  !     - There was a class not found error in your code
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the package in your composer.json (Tymon\JWTAuth)
2. if yes just composer update [pakage name]
3. composer dump-autoload

Hope it will help as it helped me.

If the above doesn't work! Just make sure your package moves from require-dev to require in the composer.json